# SP2013 REST API is not retrieving user profile properties when username has apostrophe

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I'm using REST API to get user profile properties from SP2013 and it is working for most part of users, but when I try to call for users with apostrophe on the username, I'm getting this error:

> "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-1,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"The
>   expression \\"'domain\\Joe_Doe_O'Brien'\\" is not valid.\"}}}"

On Javascript error object in the return, the status code and status text for this error are:

statusText: Bad Request

statusCode:400

This is a snippet code which I am calling SP2013 rest api:

```
var accountName = "domain\\Joe_Doe_O'Brien";
   var requestHeaders = {
           "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    };
    executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    executor.executeAsync(
          {
              url:
                  appweburl +
                  "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/getpropertiesfor(@v)?@v='" + accountName + "'",
              method: "GET",
              contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
              headers: requestHeaders,
              success: function (data) {
                  console.log(data);
              },
              error: function (jqxr, errorCode, errorThrown) {
                  console.log(jqxr.responseText);
              }
          }
          );
```

Also I have tried using encodeURIComponent in accountName variable using account name like this:

var accountName = "domain%5CJoe%5FDoe%5FO%27Brien";

But with no success, the same error still has been thrown.

Has SP2013 REST API limitation using some special char at the username to retrieve user properties?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the apostrophe?

Comment: No, I just changed apostrophe signal to %27. I have used Amit code and it is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code for encoding user name. Below method will replace ' with ''.

```
function fixedEncodeURIComponent(src) {
return encodeURIComponent(src).replace(/[']/g, function (c) {
return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) + '%' +    c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
 });
}
```

Comment: Amit, this code works, but I just did a fix on the first return, instead of encodeURIComponent(src).replace... , I changed to src.replace...
Your code was removing \\ between domain and username.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the apostrophe in account name with double apostrophes.

Example:

```
accountname.replace("'","''");

"Joe_Doe_O'Brien".replace("'","''");
```